# Does 'if and only if' flip a quantifier?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I want to understand how this sentence works, as to me it seems 'if and only if' changes meanings of the statements:

> Suppose that $a,b\in \mathbb N$. Then there exists a unique $d \in\mathbb N $ for which the following holds:
>
> an integer $m$ is a multiple of $d$ if and only if $m = ax+ by$ for some $x, y\in\mathbb Z$.

"$m = ax + by$ for some integers $x,y.$"

As $m$ is not defined, $m$ can be every number made up that way, which means 'for all'.

On the other if an integer $m$ is a multiple of $d,$ then $m = ax+ by$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb Z,$ which means 'for some' rather than 'for all'.

Comment: No, it means "there are $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $m=ax+by$", which is in fact the proper English meaning of "for some".

Comment: No, "for some" means "there exists."

Comment: If $m$ is a multiple of $d$, then there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m=ax+by$. And if we consider for arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ the integer $m=ax+by$, then $m$ is a multiple of $d$, i.e. for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m$ as above is multiple of $d$.

Comment: "as $m$ is not defined $m$ can be every number made up that way. which means for all" - can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: It's "[An integer $m$ is a multiple of $d$] if and only if [$m=ax+by$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$]."  Not "[[An integer $m$ is a multiple of $d$] if and only if [$m=ax+by$]] for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$."  In other words, the existential clause is inside the if-and-only-if clause.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Suppose that $a,b\in \mathbb N$. Then there exists a unique $d \in\mathbb N $ for which the following holds:
> >
> > an integer $m$ is a multiple of $d$ if and only if $m = ax+ by$ for some $x, y\in\mathbb Z$.

This means: $$\forall a{\in}\mathbb N\;\forall b{\in}\mathbb N\;\exists! d{\in}\mathbb N\;\forall m{\in}\mathbb N\;\big(\exists k{\in}\mathbb Z\; m=kd\iff \exists x{\in}\mathbb Z\; \exists y{\in}\mathbb Z\; m=ax+by\big).\tag1$$

> As $m$ is not defined, $m$ can be every number made up that way, which means 'for all'.

Well yes, there is an implicit "for all $m$" after the colon.

> On the other if an integer $m$ is a multiple of $d,$ then $m = ax+
> by$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb Z,$ which means 'for some' rather than
> 'for all'.

Statement $(1)$ can be rewritten as $$\forall a{\in}\mathbb N\;\forall b{\in}\mathbb N\;\exists! d{\in}\mathbb N\;\bigg(\forall m{\in}\mathbb N\;\color{red}{\forall k{\in}\mathbb Z}\; \big(m=kd\implies \exists x{\in}\mathbb Z\; \exists y{\in}\mathbb Z\; m=ax+by\big)\\\land \forall m{\in}\mathbb N\;\color{red}{\forall x{\in}\mathbb Z\; \forall y{\in}\mathbb Z}\; \big(m=ax+by\implies \exists k{\in}\mathbb Z\; m=kd\big)\bigg).$$ Does this resolve your query?

> Does 'if and only if' flip a quantifier?

Not per se.